# What's the + in find /path/ -exec command '{}' + do?

Tags: find

What's the `+` in `find /path/ -exec command '{}' +` do? as opposed to `find /path/ -exec command '{}' \;`

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The '+' makes one big command line out of all found files to minimize the number of commands to be run.

Given the case that a find command finds four files.

```
find . -type f -exec command '{}' \;
```

would produce

```
command file1
command file2
command file3
command file4
```

On the other hand

```
find . -type f -exec command '{}' \+
```

produces

```
command file1 file2 file3 file4
```

Comment: If you know `xargs`, `-exec … {} +` does the same as `-print | xargs …`, but without the quoting issues (`-print0 | xargs -0` is another way, but it's less portable).

Answer (score 4):

From the man page:

> -exec command {} +
>
> This  variant  of the -exec action runs the specified command on
>                 the selected files, but the command line is built  by  appending
>                 each  selected file name at the end; the total number of invocations of the command will  be  much  less  than  the  number  of
>                 matched  files.   The command line is built in much the same way
>                 that xargs builds its command lines.  Only one instance of  `{}'
>                 is  allowed  within the command.  The command is executed in the
>                 starting directory.

Comment: man that's very... terse? I find it to be lacking in depth, and clarity.

Comment: The idea is not to blindly spawn one process for each file, but to gather the filenames together and call the command fewer times. An example:
instead of creating 3 different "rm FILENAME" processes, it gathers the filenames and does "rm FILE1 FILE2 FILE3".

Comment: IIRC some versions of xargs have an option to batch these names together up to a specified limit, so you can benefit from this but also avoid overflowing when you have a large list, too.

Comment: (Find, itself, is a scary little language all its own!)

Comment: `find` gives me a semi.