# Debian sed: can't read

Tags: bash, debian, sed

I'm trying to run a command to remove `require_once` from php files from [here](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/performance.classloading.html#performance.classloading.striprequires.sed) (code below), but I am getting the error:

> sed: can't read -: No such file or directory

I am in the correct folder; what's the problem?

```
find . -name '*.php' -not -wholename '*/Loader/Autoloader.php' \
  -not -wholename '*/Application.php' -print0 | \
  xargs -0 sed --regexp-extended --in-place 's/(require_once)/\/\/ \1/g'
```

**Update:**

If I run:

```
find . -name '*.php' -not -wholename '*/Loader/Autoloader.php' \
  -not -wholename '*/Application.php' -print0
```

I get:

> find: invalid predicate `-wholename'

I tried this and it returned a list of all the files:

```
find . -name '*.php' -not -name '*/Loader/Autoloader.php' \
  -not -name '*/Application.php' -print0
```

But then changing the original to reflect this:

```
find . -name '*.php' -not -name '*/Loader/Autoloader.php' \
  -not -name '*/Application.php' -print0 | \ xargs -0 sed --regexp-extended --in-place 's/(require_once)/\/\/ \1/g'
```

Gives the error:

> -bash:  xargs: command not found

FYI, I'm running sed version 4.1.2 and I'm a bit a lost in the command line already, so please explain answers

Comment: Works for me. Replace "xargs -0 sed" with "xargs -0 echo sed". What's the output of that?

Comment: Can't get past the -bash: xargs: command not found error

Comment: The `-bash: xargs: command not found` error is because of the backslash immediately before `xargs`. If you remove the backslash or if there's a newline after the backslash, it should work.

Comment: @ Dennis, make that an answer and it's all yours. Worked a charm

Comment: Actually, turns out that it commented even the ones it wasn't supposed to but I can live with uncommenting a few lines

Comment: Why are you piping find to xargs can't `-exec` do it for you? maybe read [this question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/3682/29)

Answer (score 1):

The error seems to indicate that sed tries to read from *stdin*. Have you tried just the *find* part to see if it returns any file?

Comment: If I modify the -wholename to -name it works (without the rest of the code)

Answer (score 1):

Your second invocation doesn't make any sense, why the "\ " before the xarsg? You try to call a program called " xargs", and bash tells you it can't find it (note the double blank after the colon), which is hardly surprising.

To get rid of the error case where sed hangs when xargs returns zero files (because it's trying to read from stdin when there are no command line arguments), you should add -r to your xargs arguments.

Comment: It's from the Zend Framework docs, I didn't write it (and wouldn't know how)

Answer (score 0):

What version of `sed` do you have?  POSIX sed doesn't understand double-dash options, neither does minised, but GNU sed does.

For something more portable (and IMO nicer), try `sed -i '/require_once/s![[:space:]]*!&// !'`.

Comment: I don't think `sed -i` is any more portable than `sed --in-place`, it's a GNU extension anyway. FreeBSD also has it, but the suffix argument is compulsory, to you have to write `sed -i .bak` or `sed -i ''`.

Comment: sed v4.1.2, please see question for update

Answer (score 0):

I prefer perl -pi.bak for these sorts of cases.

FMTYEWTK at http://www.perl.com/pub/2004/10/14/file_editing.html

(FMTYEWTK stands for Far More Than You Ever Wanted To Know)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the page that the question links to has gone away, so I can't check the original command.  Instead, I will do some guessing.

The first error comes from running GNU `sed` and doing in-place editing on a input file called `-`.  This file does not exist and you get that error:

Example (using an empty `sed` script):

```
$ sed -i -e '' -
sed: can't read -: No such file or directory
```

Where the `-` filename comes from, I don't know, but it could have something to do with not getting any filenames from `find` (see below).

You then seem to have switched to some other machine or `find` implementation, because now the `find` command no longer recognize the `-wholename` test. This error confuses me.

You then change `-wholename` to `-name`, but you should have changed it to `-path` as `-wholename` is the same as `-path` in GNU `find`.

Your `find` command still won't work, even if you change `-wholename` to `-path` since the expression you use should be a regular expression.

As a regular expression, `*/Application.php` matches the exact string `*/Application.php`.  A `*` at the start of a regular expression matches a literal `*`.  You might have meant to use `.*/Application.php`, but this would have been the same as `-name "Application.php"`.

Taking all  of the above into consideration, and removing the `xargs` call (*that* error comes from escaping the space in front of the command name, which then becomes part of the actual command name, which can't be found):

```
find . -type f -name '*.php' \
    ! -path '.*/Loader/Autoloader.php' \
    ! -name 'Application.php' \
    -exec sed -i 's/require_once/\/\/ &/' {} +
```

This also slims down the call to GNU `sed` a bit so that it doesn't need to use extended regular expressions.

Related:

- [Understanding the -exec option of `find`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/389705)