# mv failed halfway through - is source directory intact

Tags: rename

I ran `mv a-folder /home/me` on a machine and half way through the move the destination device filled up.

`a-folder` was made up of folders and files in various subdirectories.

Does `mv` leave the source folder intact until the move has successfully completed?

**The source and destination folders were on different filesystems.**

The reason I ask is that I ran this command on the wrong machine, so if the source folder is intact then that makes my life a lot easier :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No your source folder is not intact... On the same file system all `mv` does is add and remove directory entries. But on a different filesystem... I'm not sure at what point it unlinks the file, and whether it removes data as it goes... but once a file is moved, it is unlinked.

This is unless of course you used a special option to `mv`. Some of which are mentioned in [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/4936/29) which might interest you in the future.

Comment: If moving a file to different filesystem fails, does the source file stay intact?

Answer (score 4):

xenoterracide's answer is 100% correct, I'll just add to it.

I often monitor the copy or move process of large amounts of files with:

```
watch -d -n 1 'du -sk dir1; du -sk dir2'
```

This will show you how the cumulated file size changes over time, proving to you that files are moved and removed (with mv) progressively along the way.

Comment: Thanks for that. Your username is strangely appropriate! ;)