# Move files up by a directory by depth criteria

Tags: shell-script, files, rename, mv

I have a directory tree that looks like this (simplified, in truth there are hundreds of folders):

```
.
├── a
│   └── b
│       └── a.h5
├── b
│   ├── b
│   │   └── e.h5
│   └── c
│       ├── a.h5
│       └── b.h5
├── c
│   └── b
│       └── a.h5
├── d
│   ├── a.h5
│   └── e.h5
└── e
    └── e.h5
```

Basically, some `.h5` files are at depth 1 (ex. `d/a.h5`, `e/e.h5`) and some files are are depth 2 (ex. `b/b/e.h5,` `b/c/b.h5`, ...)

I would like to move up only the files at depth 2, so that they all lie at depth one, as in:

```
.
├── a
│   └── a.h5
├── b
│   ├── e.h5
│   ├── a.h5
│   └── b.h5
├── c
│   └── a.h5
├── d
│   ├── a.h5
│   └── e.h5
└── e
    └── e.h5
```

I know that `*/*/*.h5` matches the files i'm interested in (tested via `ls */*/*.h5`), but I tried `mv */*/*.h5 */*.h5` and it made a mess.

Duplicate files would ideally be handled by renaming, but also prompting is okay.
How should I procede?

P.S: I've seen:

- https://superuser.com/questions/62141/how-to-move-all-files-from-current-directory-to-upper-directory
- [How do you bulk move files up one directory safely?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4936/how-do-you-bulk-move-files-up-one-directory-safely)

But they both apply to single directories.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Going from your directory structure:

```
$ tree
.
├── a
│   └── b
│       └── a.h5
├── b
│   ├── b
│   │   └── e.h5
│   └── c
│       ├── a.h5
│       └── b.h5
├── c
│   └── b
│       └── a.h5
├── d
│   ├── a.h5
│   └── e.h5
└── e
    └── e.h5

12 directories, 8 files
```

Use this `for` loop:

```
$ for f in */*/*.h5; do mv -v -- "$f" "${f%/*}/../"; done
»a/b/a.h5“ -> »a/b/../a.h5“
»b/b/e.h5“ -> »b/b/../e.h5“
»b/c/a.h5“ -> »b/c/../a.h5“
»b/c/b.h5“ -> »b/c/../b.h5“
»c/b/a.h5“ -> »c/b/../a.h5“
```

The **result**:

```
$ tree
.
├── a
│   ├── a.h5
│   └── b
├── b
│   ├── a.h5
│   ├── b
│   ├── b.h5
│   ├── c
│   └── e.h5
├── c
│   ├── a.h5
│   └── b
├── d
│   ├── a.h5
│   └── e.h5
└── e
    └── e.h5

12 directories, 8 files
```

**Explanation**:

```
for f in */*/*.h5; do mv -v -- "$f" "${f%/*}/../"; done
```

- `for f in */*/*.h5` loops trough all the desired files

  - `mv -v --` moves them, verbosely. `--` prevents filenames with dashes to be interpreted as arguments.
  - `"$f"` the original filename
  - `${f%/*}/../` the name of the directory containing the file, `../` added. That path is interpreted as "one directory up".

Answer (score 4):

This should be a start:

```
find . -mindepth 3 -maxdepth 3 -type f -execdir mv -i -v {} .. \;
```

the `mv -i` asks to overwrite existing files. `-execdir` changes to the directory of the file before doing the command.

Answer (score 1):

try

```
 for x in */*/*.h5
 do
    mv "$x" "$(dirname $(dirname $x))"
 done
```

if you have no strange characters in your directory names.

Or, alternatively:

```
ls */*/*.h5 | awk -F/ '{print "mv \"%s\"  \"%s/%s\" \n",$0,$1,$3 ;}' | bash
```

you can remove `| bash` to get a preview.

Comment: Your `for` loop can deal with any file name, why did you add the extremely fragile `awk/ls` one?