# How to return both file name and line number with find ... -exec grep?

Tags: grep, find

When using `find`, how do I return the file name and the line number when searching for a string? I manage to return the file name in one command and the line numbers with another one, but I can't seem to combine them.

File names: `find . -type f -exec grep -l 'string to search' {} \;`

Line numbers: `find . -type f -exec grep -n 'string to search' {} \;`

Answer (score 75, accepted):

The command line switch `-H` forces `grep` to print the file name, even with just one file.

```
% grep -n 7 test.in
7:7
% grep -Hn 7 test.in
test.in:7:7
```

---

```
   -H, --with-filename
          Print the filename for each match.
```

Note that as [Kojiro](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/5377/kojiro) says in [a comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/53072/how-to-return-both-file-name-and-line-number-with-find-exec-grep/53074#comment74330_53074), this is not part of the POSIX standard; it is in both GNU and BSD grep, but it's possible some systems don't have it (e.g. Solaris).

Comment: This answer could be improved by pointing out that the `-H` flag to `grep` is a [nonstandard GNU extension](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/grep.html) and posing an alternative approach for non-GNU systems.

Answer (score 26):

Unless you use the non-standard `-H` or `-r`/`-R` options, `grep` only outputs the file name if passed more than one file name, so you can do:

```
find . -type f -exec grep -n 'string to search' /dev/null {} +
```

With the `{} +`  syntax, `find` will pass as many files as needed to `grep`, while with `{} ';'`, it runs one `grep` per file which is inefficient.

We still add `/dev/null` (which is guaranteed to exist and be empty) which makes sure `grep` gets at least two files, for the cases where there's only one regular file in the current directory or below or the list of files has been split by `find` in such a way that the last run has only one file.

As a side note, with `-exec grep regex {} +`, `find`'s exit status will be non-zero if *any* of the `grep` invocations terminated  with a non-zero exit status. It will also be non-zero if `find` fails to traverse/read some directories or get file metadata. If `find` returns with a zero exit status, that means `find` could traverse all directories and *all* `grep` invocation succeeded (found at least one file with at least one match), but if it returns non-zero, that doesn't necessarily mean no match was found.

With `-exec grep regex {} ';'`, `grep`'s exit status is only used to determine whether the `-exec` predicate (which could be used as a condition) succeeds, it's not reflected in `find`'s exit status. So `find`'s exit status will only be about whether it could find all the files.

Comment: both + and -H work great, thank you!

Comment: And related to this answer: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3682/whats-the-in-find-path-exec-command-do

Comment: +1 Right, because causing `grep` to have multiple filename args would force it to output the matched filenames. Clever!

Answer (score 2):

If your grep supports the recursive `-r` flag, this solves your request:

```
grep -rn "String to search " *
```

Comment: That's true, but I don't see what this adds to the existing answers.

Comment: And if there’s only one (non-dot) file in the current directory, this doesn’t display the file’s name.